# c# text file format using StreamWriter

Tags: c#, visual-studio

How do i use streamwriter to not overwrite the data and get each item and put them into the right columns. Control i use are radio buttons and checkboxes.
e.g.

**size     blend type     Flavour**
small    Latte          Caramel

```
enter code here int iCount;
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("Shop Data.txt"))
        {
            for (iCount = 0; iCount < lstBasket.Items.Count; iCount++)
            {
                sw.WriteLine(lstBasket.Items[iCount]);
```

I have used this but somehow it overwrite itself.

Comment: This question is too broad. You're basically asking us to write the app for you. Ask something more specific that you would like to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See `StreamWriter w = File.AppendText("log.txt")`

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3zc0w663(v=vs.110).aspx